# Why is the SRCSET attribute not working on my website?

Tags: wordpress, srcset

I am using Wordpress 5.8.2, and have been having troubles with the srcset attribute.  I previously was using the Twenty-twelve theme, but when I failed to get the Srcset attribute to work, I switched to the Astra theme, thinking that the theme was causing the problem.  Unfortunately, I am still having problems. I have checked the site using dev tools in chrome and firefox, and the SRCSET attribute it being completely ignored in both.  The page in question is: [https://www.bakashana.org/][1] Please find the attached code.

Please note, the image in question on this page is with the URL: "https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Ruth-and-Grandma-Desktop.jpg".  This is just as an example, none of the images sitewide seem to be correctly utilizing the SRCSET attribute.  Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
/*homepage programs*/
.rTableRowHome {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    max-width:95%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
        padding-bottom:1em;
}
.rTableCellHome {
    display:flex;
    padding-left:1em;
    padding-right:1em;
}

.homeprogram {
    border-radius:3rem !important;
    width:32vw;
    border:.2em solid #7b2d26;
    margin-left:auto !important;
    margin-right:auto !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .rTableRowHome {
    flex-wrap:wrap !important;
    }
    
    .homeprogram {
    max-width:95vw;
    width:260px;
    height:auto;
    }
    
.rTableCellHome {
    margin-bottom:1em;
    order:-1 !important;
    
}
    .rTableCellHome1 {
    margin-bottom:1em;
  order:1 !important;
}

}
/*homepage header text adj*/
#textblockblackhome {
    padding-top:.5em;
    text-align:center;
}

@media screen and (min-width:881px) {
    #textblockblackhome p{
        max-width:70vw;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:880px) {
#textblockblackhome {
padding-top:.5em;
}}
#sponsorhomepage {
text-align:center;
border-top:.2em solid #7b2d26;
border-bottom:.2em solid #7b2d26;
padding-top:0px;
margin-top:0px;
}

/*meet grantees seeking sponsors on homepage */
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
.seekingsponsorhomerow {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
  padding-top:.7%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.seekingsponsorhomerow img{
    border-radius:3em;
    max-width:12.5vw !important;
}
        .seekingsponsorhomerow a{
        font-size:100% !important;
    }
    
.seekingsponsorhome {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
    order:0 !important;
}
    .seekingsponsorhome1 {
        max-width:30vw; !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)  {
    .seekingsponsorhomerow {
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        flex-direction:row;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        padding-top:0px !important;
        padding-bottom:1em;
     overflow:hidden !important;
}

    }
    .seekingsponsorhomerow h2{
        padding-top:0px;
        margin-top:0px;
        line-height:1.2;
    }
    
    .seekingsponsorhomerow a{
        font-size:80%;
    }
.seekingsponsorhome {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    padding-left:1%;
    padding-right:1%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
    order:1;
        padding-bottom:.5em;
    }
    .seekingsponsorhomerow img{
            border-radius:3em;
        border:.2em solid #7b2d26;
max-width:20vw;
margin-left:2% auto;
margin-right:2% auto;
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;
}

.seekingsponsorhome1 {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-items:center;
    padding-left:5%;
    padding-right:5%;
}

.ourimpactrow {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    align-items:center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    
}
.ourimpactcell {
    padding:.5em;
}
.ourimpactcell2 {
    padding:.5em;
}

#textblockblackhome {
    padding-left:0em !important;
    padding-right:0em !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width:929px) {
    .ourimpactcell2 {
    border-top:.2em solid white !important;
    }
}
.ourimpactcell img {
    border-radius:2em
}
.yep-youtube {
    border-radius:2em;
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
.yep-wrapper {
    max-width:90vw !important;
}
.yepPlayButton {
    left:35% !important;
    
}
}


.homep {
    margin-top:1% !important;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="contentafterheader">
<div id="content-desktop">

<img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Ruth-and-Grandma-Desktop.jpg" alt="Bakashana's first university graduate" class="headerimage"
srcset=
     "https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Ruth-and-Grandma-Desktop.jpg 1920w,
      https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Ruth-and-Grandma-Desktop-1024x315.jpg 1024w, 
      https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Ruth-and-Grandma-Desktop-768x236.jpg 768w,
      https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Ruth-and-Grandma-Desktop-624x192.jpg 624w"
sizes="(min-width: 880px) 100vw,
    100vw"
 /> 

<div class="textblockblack" id="textblockblackhome">
<p><b>Our mission is to inspire Zambian youth, specifically girls, by providing them a future of choice through education, livelihood training, health services, leadership mentoring, and cultural exchange.  </b></p></div>


<div class="textblockmargin" id="sponsorhomepage">
<div class="seekingsponsorhomerow">
<div class="seekingsponsorhome"><a href="/sponsor-a-young-woman" target="blank" rel="noopener"><img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-3731" src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Mwango-Kalaluka-Headshot.jpg" alt="Kalaluka Mwango Emily" width="150" height="150" /></a></div>
<div class="seekingsponsorhome"><a href="/sponsor-a-young-woman" target="blank" rel="noopener"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Theresa-Chileshe-Headshot.jpg" alt="Sponsor a young woman" width="150" height="150" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-9610" /></a></div>
<div class="seekingsponsorhome1"><h2><a href="/sponsor-a-young-woman" target="blank" rel="noopener">Meet the Young Women Seeking Sponsorship</a></h2></div>
<div class="seekingsponsorhome"><a href="/sponsor-a-young-woman" target="blank" rel="noopener"><img src=https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Grace-Mwambazi-Headshot.jpg" alt="Grace scholarship zambia" width="150" height="150" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-4900" /></a></div>
<div class="seekingsponsorhome"><a href="/sponsor-a-young-woman" target="blank" rel="noopener"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Miga-Sheba-Headshot.png" alt="Miga Sponsor" width="150" height="150" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-4786" /></a></div></div></div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Our Programs</h1>
<div class="rTableHome">
<div class="rTableBodyHome">
<div class="rTableRowHome">
<div class="rTableCellHome">
<a href="/education"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Education-Homepage-608.jpg" alt="education" class="homeprogram" /></a>
</div>
<div class="rTableCellHome1">
<a href="/bakashana-resource-center/"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/resource-center-homepage.jpg" alt="resource center services" class="homeprogram" /></a></div>
<div class="rTableCellHome">
<a href="/health"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/healthmainpage.jpg" alt="health services kasama"  class="homeprogram" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="content-mobile">
<img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Ruth-and-Grandma-mobile.jpg" alt="Bakashana's first university graduate" class="headerimage" 
srcset="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Ruth-and-Grandma-mobile.jpg 880w,
        https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Ruth-and-Grandma-mobile-400x123 400w," />
<div class="textblockblack" id="textblockblackhome">
<p><b>Our mission is to inspire Zambian youth, specifically girls, by providing them a future of choice through education, livelihood training, health services, leadership mentoring, and cultural exchange.  </b></p></div>
<div class="textblockmargin" id="sponsorhomepage">
<div class="seekingsponsorhomerow">
<div class="seekingsponsorhome"><a href="/sponsor-a-young-woman" target="blank" rel="noopener"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/highcompress-Christine-thumbnail-150x150.jpg" alt="christine zambia scholarship kasama" width="150" height="150" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-6483" /></a></div>
<div class="seekingsponsorhome"><a href="/sponsor-a-young-woman" target="blank" rel="noopener"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Theresa-Mutale-Thumbnail.jpg" alt="Sponsor a young woman" width="150" height="150" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-9610" /></a></div>
<div class="seekingsponsorhome1"><h2><a href="/sponsor-a-young-woman" target="blank" rel="noopener">Meet the Young Women Seeking Sponsorship</a></h2></div>
<div class="seekingsponsorhome"><a href="/sponsor-a-young-woman" target="blank" rel="noopener"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Jane-Kampamba.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-4900" /></a></div>
<div class="seekingsponsorhome"><a href="/sponsor-a-young-woman" target="blank" rel="noopener"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/constance300-150x150.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" class="size-thumbnail wp-image-4786" /></a></div></div></div>

<div style="text-align:center;">
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Our Programs</h1>
<div class="rTableHome">
<div class="rTableBodyHome">
<div class="rTableRowHome">
<div class="rTableCellHome">
<a href="/education"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Education-Homepage-608-400x267.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="auto" class="homeprogram" alt="education services" /></a>
</div>
<div class="rTableCellHome1">
<a href="/bakashana-resource-center/"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/resource-center-homepage-400x267.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="auto" alt="resource center services" class="homeprogram" /></a></div>
<div class="rTableCellHome">
<a href="/health"><img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/healthmainpage-400x267.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="auto" alt="health services kasama"  class="homeprogram" /></a></div>
</div>
</div></div></div></div>

<div class="textblockblack" style="text-align:center;" id="textblockblackhome">
<h1>Our Impact</h1>
<div class="ourimpactrow">
<div class="ourimpactcell">
<a href="/2021-impact-report" target="blank" rel="noopener">
<img src="https://www.bakashana.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/impact-photo-for-newsletter-home.png" alt="2021 impact report" width="441" height="259" class="infographichome"/> <p>Check out our 2021 Impact Report</p>
</a></div>
<div class="ourimpactcell2">
[yep_youtube width="461" height="auto" nocookie="0" controls="0" start="0"]4mKh9uFELug[/yep_youtube]
<p class="homep"> See what our Grantees have to say </p></div></div></div>

<div class="textblockmargin" style="text-align:justify;"><p>Embracing a strength-based, culturally relevant approach that combines ancestral wisdom, the cultivation of healthy relationships, & access to contemporary resources, Bakashana empowers youth to be leaders in their communities. Bakashana's primary work involves the support of young women living in rural areas, who have successfully completed their grade 7 education, yet lack the financial or familial resources to attend secondary school (grades 8-12). Bakashana specifically targets young women living near Kasama, the provincial capital of Zambia’s Northern Province.</p>

<p>Bakashana is a Bemba word that refers to a young woman. With different emphasis, it also can mean “the dancer.” Our program is dedicated to working with young women from rural areas as they discover the joy of their work, community and life.</p></div></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: When i tested in console 1024w was returning empty. After i clear the cache it shows up. Maybe its just cache issue ?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).